# In mobile screen I want to delete div from the third one :jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In mobile screen, I want to `delete` div from the third one, but 15 was deleted not 27, **I don't know why anyone can resolve this?**

```
   if (jQuery(window).width() < 700) {
        for (var i = 3; i < 31; i++) {
            jQuery(".status-publish").eq(i).remove();
           // alert(i);
         }
    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant `HTML` code.

Comment: @RohitSharma Why? That will only delete one, that's wrong.

Comment: The key word is `from`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:gt()`

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 700) {
  jQuery(".status-publish:gt(2)").remove();
}
```

Note:- you need to call the is code both on `document.ready` as well as `window.resize` too.

Reference:-

[:gt() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: @AhmedTrios  glad to help you :):).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for this. You can use CSS to hide elements along with a media query to detect the screen size:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .status-publish:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+31) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Note that the performance of this will be orders of magnitude quicker than JS too.

Comment: That's a very clever selector. Vote up.